# Andengine examples shows error not working

Tags: andengine

I am very new to andengine, trying to use this andengine examples from git url : https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples
But it always shows me **error on** two classes

**BoundCameraExample and in HullAlgorithmExample**

In bound camera example error is in line 220 says :

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to AnimatedSprite

```
final AnimatedSprite face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()).animate(100);
```

and in **HullAlgorithmExample error is on  import statement of DrawMode** 

error shows on line number 11 : import org.andengine.entity.primitive.vbo.DrawMode;
and in lines 168 , 175 says DrawMode cannot be resolved to a variable

I am using java compiler 1.6 for all extensions 
I downloaded andengine and extensions from the same git repo.
What is going wrong with this 
please help me

Thanks to allll

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the BoundCameraExample, try

```
final AnimatedSprite face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion,  this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
face.animate(100);
```

instead of

```
final AnimatedSprite face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion,  this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()).animate(100);
```

In the HullAlgorithExample, import

```
import org.andengine.entity.primitive.DrawMode;
```

instead of

```
import org.andengine.entity.primitive.vbo.DrawMode;
```

Comment: im also facing same problem and i read total threads related to this issue but you made very easier. Its working

Answer (score 11):

In 2014 the answer of @swati-rawat is still heplful. I found further two issues, I'll report here the solution since this question is well ranked:

in **SplitScreenExample**, as in BoundCameraExample, replace with:

```
final AnimatedSprite face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
face.animate(100);
```

in **TextBreakExample** replace with:

```
this.mText = new Text(50, 40, this.mFont, "", 1000, new TextOptions(AutoWrap.LETTERS, AUTOWRAP_WIDTH, HorizontalAlign.CENTER, Text.LEADING_DEFAULT), vertexBufferObjectManager);
```